# Simple Php Chat

Tags: php

i am working on a website in which i want to allow user to simply chat with each other but their chat should be hidden from other users..
like Registered users on web,
1. you
2.me

```
$sql= insert into table where sender = $_SESSION['user'] and receiver= $_GET['user'];
```

now table

```
id- 1
```

sender id - 1
receiver id - 2
message - hii

id- 2
sender id - 2
receiver id - 1
message - hell0

you send me hii ..
now i reply you hello..

now fetch data in message box,

```
$sql= select from table where receiver=  $_SESSION['user'] and sender= $_GET['user'];
```

but this is garbage output...

how should i fetch message then i conversation properly.. please help me , i will be very  thankful to you..

sorry for bad English....

Comment: use `order by time` to get conversation properly

Comment: ^ Assuming the *chat* table actually has a time column of course... I mean, it *should*, but...

Comment: if i use this query that are listed above, the message content does not listed in right format.. it shows top in all send message and bottom in all receive message... like      top 1 - hii 3 - fine and you  bottom 2 - hello, how r you? 4 - i am also fine